# Wordpress bug after creating a custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-gutenberg

I'm using [ACF](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/) to create custom fields in my custom post types. It all works fine but the Ui of the default editor is not adding any margin to the bottom of the screen and the ACF field is not accessible. Please check the screenshot to understand better.
[image]

Is there a way to add spacing at the bottom or a workaround to make the field accessible?

Comment: Rather than work around the issue with CSS. The bigger question is... what script isn't working right, and why?  Is there anything showing in the console?  Things that should be working, but aren't, usually have a good reason.

Comment: The console is clean. It's a fresh install and this is the only CPT that's created. No other custom script nor any additional plugin are added. It might be a bug with ACF or the new editor when used together with ACF. @HowardE

Comment: Ok. Sure. I'm dubious, but ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a `margin` between both by injecting a bit of css via a the `admin_head` action hook in your `function.php` file.

```
<?php
    add_action( 'admin_head', 'admin_script' );
    function admin_script() {
    echo '
    <style media="screen">
        div.postbox-container {
            margin-bottom: 25px;
        }
    </style>';
    }; 
?>
```

Comment: Thanks! This method works but it affects all the post types. I've targeted a class that's unique to ACF and it worked.

Comment: Glad I could help, don't forget to accept the answer